# c++ floating pointer to the power of int pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, floating-point, int, cin

I have a method that takes in a float pointer and an int pointer, it with then do `pow(the float, the int)` and return the value. I get a huge error of which I can't seem to understand what it is telling me is wrong.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float method3(float *f, int *i); //initialize pointer method

float flt; //init variable
int nt; //init variable
int main() {
    method3(*flt, *nt); //run method 3, which will do the same math, but with pointers instead of value or reference
    cout << flt; //print it out
    return 0;
}

float method3(float *f, int *i) { //method 3, get float and int by pointers
    return pow(f, i); //f to power of i back to original flt variable
}
```

please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `*flt` and `*nt` doesn't make any sense. The argument to `*` has to be a pointer, not `float` or `int`.

Comment: `void` return type and returning `return pow(f, i);` is just balantly wrong! Also I can't see any reason why these parameters are passed as pointers, and not simply by value.

Comment: `return pow(*f, *i);` then, if you insist for this weird function signature!

Comment: If your compiler is not throwing a bunch of warnings at you, you need to wind up the warning level or use a better compiler !  I think it is good practice to set the warning level a little higher than is comfortable, and not run anything until all warnings have been cleared.

Comment: @OP Don't yell, be patient!

Answer (score 3):

You are dereferencing pointers improperly.

You should call

```
pow(*f,*i);
```

and

```
method3(&flt,&nt);
```

Comment: Also method3 should return some value instead of void

Comment: Good call.  Use `float method3(float* f, int* i);`

Answer (score 0):

`method3` returns `void`, so you can't write `return pow(f, i);` inside it.

Comment: I know this, that isn't the problem. But Ian already fixed it.